# Can't find '__main__' module when executing command-line script with python

Tags: python, command-line, pypi

I specify that this is my first project with PyPI, so be kind :)

I have developed a command line tool in python and uploaded on PyPi (https://github.com/ferru97/PyPaperBot)

The structure of the project is the following:

```
PyPaperBot
|__PyPaperBot      
    |_ __init__.py    
    |_ __main__.py 
    |_ other stuff..
|_setup.py`
|_other stuff..
```

Since I wont this tool to be executed by command line on setup.py I've added:

```
 packages = ['PyPaperBot'],  
 entry_points={ 
 "console_scripts":["PyPaperBot = PyPaperBot.__main__:main"],
  },
```

But it seems not to work because every time I do  `py PyPaperBot` it return the following error:

```
can't find '__main__' module in 'PyPaperBot
```

Any suggestion? I tried for 4 hours

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. My fault, I was running the module with `py PyPaperBot` instead of `py -m PyPaperBot`

Answer (score 1):

I have a PyPi project with an identical project layout, and the only difference I see is with the `packages` parameter, try using `packages=setuptools.find_packages(),`. This works for me, and it is used in the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).